# Remove the first character in a string vector if it is 0 using sapply

Tags: r, string, apply

So, I know how to do this using a for loop. What I do is iterate through the entire loop, check the first character to see if it is 0, and if it is, substring the second character and go forward.

However, I wanted to know if there was a more effecient way to do this using sapply. I have to constantly iterate through the lists to do this kind of work, and knowing if there is a way to leverage apply function is something I'd love to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried gsub?

```
myvector <- c("SOME", "0WORDS", "HAVE", "0ZEROS", "IN", "0THEM")
gsub("^0", "", myvector) #The caret (^) makes sure only a starting 0 gets removed
[1] "SOME"  "WORDS" "HAVE"  "ZEROS" "IN"    "THEM"
```

Comment: That would be a lot simpler...I didn't even think of the regular expression solution, thanks!